# Folding specific arrays in JSON response in Postman

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, postman

Is there a way to fold specific arrays in JSON response in Postman through a script?

So for example I have this response and I want to fold an "attribute3" array.

My initial thought was to use "Test" tab in Postman and cycle through response to find all arrays I wanna fold but I have no idea if it is even possible.

```
[
    {
        ...,
        "attribute1": {
            "attribute2": true,
            "attribute3": [...a lot of data...]
        }
    },
    {...},
    {...}
]
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: I wanna know if there is a way to fold arrays in postman response using scripts in test tab

Comment: No. You could use the arrows on the response viewer pane or log that specific part to the console in the script though.

Comment: Yeah, I know about manual clicking to fold but the problem is 25k line JSON response :( Thx for the response anyway!

Comment: Command + K + 0 (zero)